# Prove that $V^* = W_1^0 \oplus W_2^0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is a direct sum of two subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$, prove that $V^*  = W_1^0  \oplus W_2^0$.

Where $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$ and $W^0$ is the annihilator of $W$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $W_1^0\cap W_2^0 = \{0\}$ because a form annihilating both will certainly annihilate their sum. Therefore this sum can be considered direct. So if $\rho_U = \operatorname{id}$ on $U$ and 0 elsewhere for a subspace $U \subseteq V$, we have
$$\rho_{W_1}+\rho_{W_2}= \operatorname{id}$$
And so 
$$f = f \circ(\rho_{W_1}+\rho_{W_2}) = f \circ\rho_{W_1} + f \circ\rho_{W_2 } \in W_2^0 \oplus W_1^0$$

For any $f \in V^*$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Look at $\,V^*/W_1^0\,$ and check your last question, already answered.